# If ActionResult is a class in mvc then how can we use it directly without using it's objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Demo()
{
    return View(); 
}
```

I really can't understand use of `ActionResult` in this context. 
`ActionResult` is an abstract class, we use diff methods of `ActionResult` without creating it's object. 
Logically how does it work internally ?

Answer (score 0):

`View()` is a regular function that returns some concrete subclass of `ActionResult` (in this case, `ViewResult`).

Answer (score 0):

By default the framework allows us to return various types of responses to requests. `ActionResult` is the abstract class that is inherited by various other classes that can be returned to the client. So here we return the superclass type to provide flexibility to the developer to decide which type of result to provide.

This link describes it all:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Hi @Nil , please accept the answers if you find it helpful :)